# Discount Option In Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, discount

I want to apply the 10% discount option for two of my products for which it has to show that on online purchase it show the discounted price in the invoice that will be generated for the product.

how can this be resolved ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to apply sale price to your products. You can simply have sale price (90%) of your retail price in "Special price" section.

Comment: That's Catalog Price Rules. See that article: http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/catalog-price-rules